# Reading an XML file as is (with indentation) in a variable (using Python)

Tags: python, xml, file, parsing, indentation

Is there a way to read an XML file line by line, as is, with indentation into a Python variable?

I've tried the following:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse("f1.xml")
```

and

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse("f1.xml")
t1 = ET.fromstring(tree)
```

On doing #2, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3032, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:68121)
  File "parser.pxi", line 1785, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:102459)
ValueError: can only parse strings"
```

If I use `fopen` function to read an XML file, there's a whole bunch of crap added in it - since it seems to use Microsoft Word or Open Office to read the file..

Comment: If you want to read it "as-is", then you're asking for unparsed textual content, not an XML document-model tree. Why would you be using `lxml` at all if that's what you want?

Comment: ...as for the "whole bunch of crap", you'd need to be explicit about what you do and don't want to see. If you want to read a file, metadata added by the application that created it _is_ part of the file; if you want some of that metadata thrown out, you'll need to be extremely explicit about what and how you want to be rid of.

Comment: Charles - I do want it as the XML tree (as is) without any processing instructions, I meant. If I open an XML file using vim on my terminal, I see strings like "wordDocument.. microsoft ..." which is an entire lot of crap. Crap is the font details, font size.."

Comment: I want it like data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<uimap>
    <page name="login">
        <uielement name="username">
             <locator>//input[@type='text']</locator>
        </uielement>
        <uielement name="password">
            <locator>//input[@type='password']</locator>
        </uielement>
    </page>
</uimap>
""" Not like a word document (xml has "word document" tags when opened via vim) giving details about font size and font name..

Comment: Font details, font size, &c. are data. We need a more precise specification to determine which data to keep and which to toss than just what you consider crap in your head, and ideally some sample input (for those who don't have the same version of Office you're working with handy).

Comment: <w:wordDocument xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:sl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/schemaLibrary/2003/core" xmlns:aml="http://schemas.microsoft.com/aml/2001/core" xmlns:wx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/auxHint" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" w:macrosPresent="no" w:embeddedObjPresent="no" w:ocxPresent="no" xml:space="preserve"><o:DocumentProperties></o:DocumentProperties><w:fonts>

Comment: Above is what i get from opening an xml file on vim editor. XmlFormatter fixed the indentation but not the font details like this:  <w:u w:val="single"></w:u>
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>&lt;/uielement></w:t>
        </w:r>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Monaco" w:cs="Monaco" w:h-ansi="Monaco"></w:rFonts>
            <wx:font wx:val="Monaco"></wx:font>

Comment: A "sample" that doesn't include the indentation you want to keep and doesn't parse isn't much of a sample. Use a byte-for-byte-accurate pastebin; ix.io, sprunge.us, and gist.github.com are good (if, for the latter, you use git itself as the upload tool).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59309/discussion-between-user2921139-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: Ok Charles - lets just debug it with the error I have posted in my first question on this post. How do you think I can resolve that?

Comment: "Don't do that". You can't pass an ElementTree to fromstring(), because it's not a string, it's an object. I can't tell you how to fix it because I don't know what useful thing you would expect it to actually _do_.

Comment: "I am aware" of that. I am only explaining my difficulty and showing what I am going through with that text!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import lxml.etree as etree 
x = etree.parse("filename") 
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)
```

This is what worked for me!